# JS Regexp to replace "illegal" characters to create a PHP function name

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to generate a PHP function name from URL using this regular expression (taken from [PHP Manual - User-defined functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php):

```
url = "controller/action,/param";
re = /[^a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*/g; // consecutive characters that are not in range
result = url.replace(re, "_");
```

I am expecting result to be `controller_action_param` (single underscore), but instead I am getting this as a result: `_c_o_n_t_r_o_l_l_e_r__a_c_t_i_o_n__p_a_r_a_m_`

I think that this is somehow connected to UTF-8/Unicode, but shouldn't `\x7f-\xff` part take care of it?

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kac64/3/)

Comment: It's a three-way tie for best answer!

Comment: Yeah, now I don't know who to award ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `*` to a `+`.  The `*` matches *zero or more* of the preceding characters, you want *one or more*.

```
re = /[^a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]+/g;
```

Answer (score 2):

Lose the `*` (hint: it matches 0 characters), use a `+` instead:

```
re = /[^a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]+/g;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `+` (1 or more) instead of `*` zero or more.

```
re = /[^a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]+/g;
```